# url rewriting: id just after the domain name

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I was accessing my simple `php` app with `192.1.1.1/foldername/myfile.php?user_id='123'`

After getting a domain and changing the conf file redirect to this folder. i have access this using `.htaccess` with

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ ./myfile.php?user_id=$1
```

the url i am using is like:

`myip.com/folder/123456456`

Problem is i cannot access this without writing the folder after my ip. i want to access it through `myip.com/1234556`. but it gives me error if i write `RewriteRule` like this `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ./myfile.php?user_id=$1`. How can i direct `myip.com/123456` to my folder.

Comment: `^/(.*)$` should not match anything, when you configure this in .htaccess - the leading slash has already been removed from the path at that point. And with `^(.*)$` you would create a redirect loop - because `myfile.php` matches that pattern again in the next iteration. If you just need to match numeric IDs, then use something like `^([0-9]+)$`. Otherwise, you need to exclude either `myfile.php` specifically, or all requests that match a physically existing file or folder.

Comment: @04FS sorry did not understand.  you mean to say i should write like this. `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ ./myfile.php?user_id=$1`